# How to use django login_required method

Tags: django, django-views, django-validation

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'obs/homepage.html'
```

I want to make this view accessible to only logged in users. How can I do that? I've  seen django documentation but it was for functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to setup a mixin to use in view, something like this;

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class HomePage(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'obs/homepage.html'
```

Comment: thank you so much. it worked but i need another help now. how can i redirect  a person to "obs/login/" this url if he is not logged in but wants to access "obs/homepage"

Comment: @jef Take a look at the settings, there are some defaults that handle this; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url